# How is the DOM data actually stored at lowest level by a browser? Is it stored as a Table or a Tree?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How does Browser maintain the entire list of elements present on an HTML page?
What is the internal representation?

Comment: I imagine that would be quite browser-specific. Someone else might have a better idea off the top of their head, but there might be some open source projects you could look at to give you an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, DOM is the browser internal representation of a web page. Here is a representation of a portion of the DOM pointing to the head and body tags:
[image]

And Here is a representation of a portion of the DOM showing the head tag, containing a title tag with its value:
[image]

And Here is a representation of a portion of the DOM showing the body tag, containing a link, with a value and the href attribute with its value:
[image]

When the browser retrieve HTML code from the server, there is a parser which analyzes the structure of the code, and creates a model of it. Based on this model, the browser then renders the page on the screen.

Browsers expose an API that you can use to interact with the DOM. That’s how modern JavaScript frameworks work, they use the DOM API to tell the browser what to display on the page.

More info : https://flaviocopes.com/dom/